# Returning JSON arrays with Date types for Google Charts

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a 'Timelines' chart from Google Charts. It requires a JavaScript Date type when populating with data.

My init code is like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('divChart1');
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
```

Now I'm trying to populate it via AJAX and the Date types are giving me problems.

The rows need to be populated like so:

```
dataTable.addRows([
  ['Aaa', 'A', new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2016, 12, 31)],
  ['Bbb', 'B', new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2016, 5, 31)]]);
```

Is there any way I can return a serialized collection from my AJAX service and just parse it directly, or do I need to be iterating the collection and newing up a JavaScript Date each time?

When I try `dataTable.addRows(JSON.parse(result.chartData));` I get the following error: `Error: Type mismatch. Value 2015-08-26T11:59:23.889004+02:00 does not match type date in column index 2`

For info purposes, this is how it looks on the AJAX service:

```
List<List<object>> chartData = new List<List<object>>();

chartData.Add(new List<object>() { 
    "Aaa",
    "A",
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3)
});

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartData);
```

**edit:** Well I've got it working. Still tweaking but this is the gist:

```
chartData.Add(new List<object>() { 
    "Aaa",
    "A",
    DateTime.Now.Year + "#" + DateTime.Now.Month + "#" + DateTime.Now.Day,
    DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).Year + "#" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).Month + "#" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).Day
});

var result = $.parseJSON(result.chartData);
$.each(result, function (k, v) {
    var s = v[2].split('#');
    var e = v[3].split('#');
    dataTable.addRow([v[0], v[1], new Date(s[0], s[1], s[2]), new Date(e[0], e[1], e[2])]);
});
```

Not going to use this as the official answer because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You could make your own subclass of [DateTimeConverterBase](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DateTimeConverterBase.htm) along the lines of [How to convert new Date(year, month, day) overload with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577833/how-to-convert-new-dateyear-month-day-overload-with-json-net).

Comment: Have you tried the JSON date format?  In javascript you get it via `(new Date()).toJSON();`

Comment: Aren't you stripping the time of day information when you do `new Date(2014, 1, 1)`?  Your test case uses `DateTime.Now` which includes time of day.

Comment: @dbc, I only need year/month/day. I was using `DateTime.Now` for an example. I have tried formatting the Date on the server side and it still gives issues. I suppose I could have made this question clearer but tbh I'm still thinking about the problem let alone trying to solve it

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

While the JSON was created as requested in your original question, it appears `JSON.parse('new Date(2014, 1, 1)')` does not work because JavaScript date constructors are not [strictly valid JSON](http://json.org/).

Thus it appears you should serialize your `DateTime` as a *string* and pass a [reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to `JSON.parse()` that recognizes the date string and constructs a JavaScript `Date`.  For example:

- [How to parse JSON to receive a Date object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript/14509447#14509447) shows how to create a reviver function that recognizes dates in [Microsoft format](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/dates-and-json).  To output dates in this format use the setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateFormatHandling.htm).
- For a date string in ISO date format, see the examples of revivers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), here: [JavaScript JSON Date Parsing and real Dates](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates), or here: [How to use JSON.parse reviver parameter to parse date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792865/how-to-use-json-parse-reviver-parameter-to-parse-date-string).

**Original Answer**

You could extend [`JavaScriptDateTimeConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.htm) to write and read dates in the format `new Date(2014, 1, 1 [, H [, M [, S [, MS]]]])` (I am extending [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577833/how-to-convert-new-dateyear-month-day-overload-with-json-net) which only does reading not writing):

```
public class JavaScriptYMDDateTimeConverter : JavaScriptDateTimeConverter
{
    public bool StripTimeOfDay { get; set; }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
            // Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent local time.
            var date = ((DateTime)value).ToLocalTime();

            writer.WriteStartConstructor("Date");
            writer.WriteValue(date.Year);
            writer.WriteValue(date.Month - 1);
            writer.WriteValue(date.Day);

            if (!StripTimeOfDay)
            {
                var written = date.Date;
                var epsilon = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);

                // Only write hours, min, sec, ms if needed.
                if (date < written - epsilon || date > written + epsilon)
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(date.Hour);
                    written = written.AddHours(date.Hour);
                }

                if (date < written - epsilon || date > written + epsilon)
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(date.Minute);
                    written = written.AddMinutes(date.Minute);
                }

                if (date < written - epsilon || date > written + epsilon)
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(date.Second);
                    written = written.AddSeconds(date.Second);
                }

                if (date < written - epsilon || date > written + epsilon)
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(date.Millisecond);
                    written = written.AddMilliseconds(date.Millisecond);
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndConstructor();
        }
        else
        {
            // DateTimeOffset
            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for type {0} at path {1}", objectType.Name, reader.Path));
            return null;
        }
        if (token.Type != JTokenType.Constructor)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }
        var constructor = (JConstructor)token;
        if (!string.Equals(constructor.Name, "Date", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }

        var values = constructor.Values().ToArray();

        if (values.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }
        else if (values.Length == 1)
        {
            // Assume ticks
            using (var subReader = constructor.CreateReader())
            {
                while (subReader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartConstructor)
                    subReader.Read();
                return base.ReadJson(subReader, objectType, existingValue, serializer); // Use base class to convert
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var year = (values.Length > 0 ? (int)values[0] : 0);
            var month = (values.Length > 1 ? (int)values[1] : 0) + 1; // c# months go from 1 to 12, JavaScript from 0 to 11
            var day = (values.Length > 2 ? (int)values[2] : 0);
            var hour = (values.Length > 3 ? (int)values[3] : 0);
            var min = (values.Length > 4 ? (int)values[4] : 0);
            var sec = (values.Length > 5 ? (int)values[5] : 0);
            var ms = (values.Length > 6 ? (int)values[6] : 0);

            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
            // Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent local time.
            var dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, ms, DateTimeKind.Local);
            if (type == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
                return new DateTimeOffset(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new JavaScriptYMDDateTimeConverter { StripTimeOfDay = true } } }; 
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartData, settings);
```

Which outputs

> ```
> [["Aaa","A",new Date(2015,7,26),new Date(2015,10,26)]]
> ```

Comment: Well sh.t. All that for a stranger. Thanks mate, will give this a try. If I end up doing it a different way I hope it's not bad karma :)

Comment: I'm getting `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 21 of the JSON data` when trying `dataTable.addRows(JSON.parse(result.chartData));`, and `Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array
Source` when trying `dataTable.addRows(result.chartData);`. This looks promising though

Comment: @user982119 - I'm a c# programmer not a JavaScript programmer, but it would seem [`JSON.parse()`](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) does not support the `new Date(2015,10,26)` syntax, perhaps because it's [not valid JSON](http://json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can placing the dates in brackets

Eg

```
{
      "cols": [
            {"label": "Date", "type": "date"},
            {"label": "Serie 1", "type": "number"},
            {"label": "Serie 2", "type": "number"},
      ],
      "rows": [
            {"c":[{"v": "Date(2014, 1, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 400}]},
            {"c":[{"v": "Date(2014, 2, 25)"}, {"v": 1170}, {"v": 460}]},
            {"c":[{"v": "Date(2014, 3, 15)"}, {"v": 660}, {"v": 1120}]},
            {"c":[{"v": "Date(2014, 4, 30)"}, {"v": 1030}, {"v": 540}]},
      ]
}
```

Note the recommendations of Google about the Date constructor and browsers:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes